# POSTING form contents using AJAX/JSON/JAVASCRIPT to a PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I've been looking around for an explanation on how to do this for a while but haven't found a decent explanation yet, so apologies if this is a repeat.

I don't have any problem retrieving JSON using GET but I'm confused as to how to use POST to send JSON and have it interpreted at the far end by a PHP script

I'm trying to do this on localhost for now.

Form is as follows:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 spacer">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 topSpaceNeeded"><h4>Select Currencies to Exchange</h4></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 spacer">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <form id="formSendDataWithAjax" method="POST" action="./postedJsonData">
            <div id="formSection1">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="userId">User ID</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="userId" name="userId">
                                <option value="123456">123456</option>
                                <option value="654321">654321</option>
                                <option value="134256">134256</option>
                                <option value="652431">652431</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="originatingCountry" id="countryLabel">Country of Origin</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="originatingCountry" name="originatingCountry">
                                <option value="IE">IRELAND</option>
                                <option value="EN">ENGLAND</option>
                                <option value="FR">FRANCE</option>
                                <option value="PL">POLAND</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="currencyFrom">Base Currency</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="currencyFrom" name="currencyFrom" >
                                <option value="AUD">AUD</OPTION>
                                <option value="CAD">CAD</OPTION>
                                <option value="CHF">CHF</OPTION>
                                <option value="CZK">CZK</OPTION>
                                <option value="DKK">DKK</OPTION>
                                <option value="EUR" SELECTED>EUR</OPTION>
                                <option value="GBP">GBP</OPTION>
                                <option value="HKD">HKD</OPTION>
                                <option value="HUF">HUF</OPTION>
                                <option value="NOK">NOK</OPTION>
                                <option value="NZD">NZD</OPTION>
                                <option value="PLN">PLN</OPTION>
                                <option value="SEK">SEK</OPTION>
                                <option value="USD">USD</OPTION>
                                <option value="ZAR">ZAR</OPTION>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="currencyTo">Buy Currency</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="currencyTo" name="currencyTo">
                                <option value="AUD">AUD</OPTION>
                                <option value="CAD">CAD</OPTION>
                                <option value="CHF">CHF</OPTION>
                                <option value="DKK">DKK</OPTION>
                                <option value="EUR" SELECTED>EUR</OPTION>
                                <option value="GBP">GBP</OPTION>
                                <option value="HKD">HKD</OPTION>
                                <option value="HUF">HUF</OPTION>
                                <option value="NOK">NOK</OPTION>
                                <option value="NZD">NZD</OPTION>
                                <option value="PLN">PLN</OPTION>
                                <option value="SEK">SEK</OPTION>
                                <option value="USD">USD</OPTION>
                                <option value="ZAR">ZAR</OPTION>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="formSection2">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="rate" id="rateLabel">&nbsp;</label>
                            <input type="hidden" id="rate" name="rate" value="" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="amountSell">You Sell:</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" step="0.10" id="amountSell" name="amountSell" value="1.00" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="amountBuy">You Buy:</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" step="0.01" id="amountBuy" name="amountBuy" value="1.00" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="submit" id="transfer" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="transfer" name="transfer" value="TRANSFER NOW">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

I know it's probably easier to use JQuery, but Javascript is what I know so I'd like to stick with that if possible.

The Javascript is as follows:

```
document.getElementById('formSendDataWithAjax').onsubmit       =submitDataWithAjax;

function submitDataWithAjax(e)
{
// intercept form submission by preventing the script from following the url of the form
e.preventDefault();

var f = e.target,
    formData= new FormData(f),
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("POST", f.action);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json; charset=utf-8");
xhr.send(formData);
}
```

What I believe this script should do is prevent the postedJsonData page from loading when the form is submitted. Instead, the data is converted to JSON and should then be sent via AJAX to the postedJsonData PHP script

If this is correct, how do I get postedJsonData script to listen for the data?

Is it enough to do this to extract it to an array?

```
$dataArr = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is much easier, I'd highly recommend it.

To use jQuery, just include this at the top of your page:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Then, to do AJAX/JSON/PHP requests, replace what you currently have in your Javascript file with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#formSendDataWithAjax").submit(function() { //Whenever form with ID="formSendDataWithAjax" is submitted
        $.ajax({ //Make AJAX POST call
          type: "POST", //POST, instead of GET
          url: "postedJsonData.php", //Location of PHP script
          dataType: "JSON", //JSON
          data: {
               userid: $("#userId").val(), //These values will be JSON-encoded automatically
               country: $("#originatingCountry").val(), //Magically JSON-encoded
               etc.
          }
        }).done(function(returnValue) { //returnValue could be any JSON string: "{ "result" : "success" }, { "result" : "error" }, etc.
            alert("Your PHP script returned this value: "+returnValue);
        });
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then in your PHP script, simply calling `$_POST['userid']` or `$_POST['country']` will give you the value POSTed by the AJAX call. E.g.

```
<?php
    $userid = (int) $_POST['userid'];
    $country = $_POST['country'];

    //Do stuff
?>
```

Comment: Great that, seems to work fine. Thanks
Just one more question. please. Your JQuery looks to open an alert box with a returned result from the PHP script to indicate success or failure. When I try to return a result from the PHP script after receiving the data, it will just print out the JSON result on the same page when I echo the JSON. 
If I use the "return" command it does nothing either
How do I get it to return a result back to the JQuery which will open it in the alert box like that? Sorry, I'm new to this

Comment: Actually I was incorrect on my last comment, in that it's not really working correctly. What seems to be happening is that even with event.preventDefault(); included, on submission the page is directing to the default action and loads the controller function url located in the form action. In that controller function I have PHP of 
echo json_encode(array('result' => 'success')); to return the result
So, this displays {"result":"success"} in the browser window instead of sending it back as a response to the JQuery request, which is incorrect. How do I fix?

Comment: Add `return false;` to the end of your `$("#formSendDataWithAjax").submit(function() {` function. Also, make sure you're calling your jQuery after document loads - I've modified the script to include this.